# angular2 how to change the default prefix of component to stop tslint warnings

Tags: angular

It seems, when I create an Angular 2 app using Angular cli. My default component prefix is app-root for AppComponent. Now, when I change the selector to something else say "abc-root"

```
@Component({
  selector: 'abc-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

vscode warns me,

```
[tslint] The selector of the component "AppComponent" should have prefix "app"
```

Answer (score 337, accepted):

You need to modify two files tslint.json and .angular-cli.json, suppose you want to change to ***myprefix***:

**In the tslint.json file just modify the following 2 attributes:**

```
"directive-selector": [true, "attribute", "app", "camelCase"],
"component-selector": [true, "element", "app", "kebab-case"],
```

change "app" to "myprefix"

```
"directive-selector": [true, "attribute", "myprefix", "camelCase"],
"component-selector": [true, "element", "myprefix", "kebab-case"],
```

**In the angular.json file just modify the attribute prefix:**
*(For angular version less than 6, the file name is .angular-cli.json)*

```
"app": [
  ...
  "prefix": "app",
  ...
```

change "app" to "myprefix"

```
"app": [
  ...
  "prefix": "myprefix",
  ...
```

**If in the case you need more than one prefix as [@Salil Junior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2531302/salil-junior) point out:**

```
"component-selector": [true, "element", ["myprefix1", "myprefix2"], "kebab-case"],
```

**If creating a new project using Angular cli use this command line option**

```
ng new project-name --prefix myprefix
```

Comment: I also got a warning from `ng generate component` even after updating `tslint.json`: `You are using different prefix from app, you might get lint errors. Please update "tslint.json" accordingly.` I had to update the `apps.prefix` property in `.angular-cli.json` to get rid of that warning.

Comment: I have tried above methods but still get error - [tslint] The selector of the component "PrgAxcShiftChartComponent" should have prefix "app" (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-07) (component-selector). Please help.   Using selector as : 'prg-axc-shift-chart',

Comment: What if you don't want to enforce a prefix, but still want to enforce camelCase? Is that a possibility? I used the array syntax and added an empty string to it and that seemed to work, but not sure if that's the ideal way or not.

Comment: Please note that in Angular 6 an additional `tslint.json` file can be found in `<your-project>/src/tslint.json` which contains the component and directive selector rules. If you've applied the above fix and it's still not working for you, make sure you check that this file isn't overruling your global configuration. (https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/issues/620#issuecomment-394131604)

Answer (score 23):

1. Adjust your `angular-cli.json`: "prefix": "defaultPrefix" so that angular-cli will use that for generating components.
2. Ajust `tslint.json` like this:

   ```
   "directive-selector": [
     true,
     "attribute",
     ["prefix1", "prefix2", "prefix3"],
     "camelCase"
   ],
   "component-selector": [
     true,
     "element",
     ["prefix1", "prefix2", "prefix3"],
     "kebab-case"
   ],
   ```

Answer (score 20):

For `angular 6/7` onwards there will be a `tslint.json` inside your `/src` folder which holds the `tslist` rules for your component and directives.

```
{
    "extends": "../tslint.json",
    "rules": {
        "directive-selector": [
            true,
            "attribute",
            "directivePrefix",
            "camelCase"
        ],
        "component-selector": [
            true,
            "element",
            "compoenent-prefix",
            "kebab-case"
        ]
    }
}
```

Changing in that file will fix the problem.

Comment: Or removing it, so it stops overriding the main `tslint.json` file.

Comment: Change it how? Is what you are showing before or after the change?

Comment: @PaulRooney you can see for the `directive-selector` I added `"directivePrefix"` which will be prefix for directive and same for components

Comment: Did this go away in Angular 8?

Answer (score 16):

Actually, with Angular Cli, you can just change the "prefix" tag, inside the "apps" array on your `angular-cli.json`, located on the root app.

Changing for "TheBestPrefix", like this.

```
"apps": [
  {
    "root": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "assets": [
      "assets",
      "favicon.ico"
    ],
    "index": "index.html",
    "main": "main.ts",
    "test": "test.ts",
    "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
    "prefix": "TheBestPrefix",
    "mobile": false,
    "styles": [
      "styles.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [],
    "environments": {
      "source": "environments/environment.ts",
      "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
      "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  }
]
```

When you generate a new component using CLI, `ng g component mycomponent`
the component tag will have the following name `"TheBestPrefix-mycomponent"`

Comment: but that doesnt fix where (on purpose) some components have been generated via cli with a different prefix than the basic application's prefix

Comment: For WebStorm, this didn't work for me. Had to change tslint.json to prevent the warning as mentioned in the question. Changing angular-cli.json only helps with generating new components/directives.

Answer (score 1):

For angular 13:

If you used `ng lint` to preinitialize the linting process:

You have a pregenerated `.eslintrc.json` file.

In this file, the prefix is mentionned, simply change it as an array and it will work.

Here we add "mynewprefix" as a valid prefix for the lint:

```json
"rules": {
  "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
    "error",
    {
      "type": "attribute",
      "prefix": ["app", "mynewprefix"],
      "style": "camelCase"
    }
  ],
  "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
    "error",
    {
      "type": "element",
      "prefix": ["app", "mynewprefix"],
      "style": "kebab-case"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**tslint.json**

"component-selector": [true, "element", "app", "kebab-case"]

this 'kebab-case' force any component selector to be with this '-' case.

**for example** you can have selector like '**app-test**', '**app-my**' like this.

And as far as your error concern you must start component selector with 'app' as I have just mentioned in example.

I don't think you should make any change in tslint.json , although it would resolve your issue, but its not good practice to change in tslint.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Aniruddha pointing out the changes in angular 7:

create `tslint.json` in `src/app/shared` to extend the `app/tslint.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tslint.json",
  "rules": {
    "directive-selector": [
      true,
      "attribute",
      "shared",
      "camelCase"
    ],
    "component-selector": [
      true,
      "element",
      "shared",
      "kebab-case"
    ]
  }
}
```

One thing - If in app.component.spec you mock a component from shared module, it will complain that your mocks selector starts with 'shared' instead of  starting with 'app'. I suppose that makes sense - i should be creating my mocks in the module from whence they came.

Answer (score 0):

If there is **multiple .eslintrc.json** files in your **Angular workspace**, you need to change the prefix key accordingly.

*Verify in files,*

- /projects/<project-name>/.eslintrc.json
- /.eslintrc.json

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angular 17, the file to update is angular.json
change "prefix": "app" to  "prefix": "xyz"

xyz being the name you want to give.
From there if you create a new component let's say login, the selector will be xyz-login