# TSLINT- Overriding rules for specif file or directory

Tags: eslint, tslint

Is it possible to override rules for specific files in TSLINT (tslint.json) like  a configuration along those lines:

```
"overrides": [{
  "files": [ "*.spec.js" ],
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-expressions": 0
  }
}]
```

I wouldnt want to set a comment on each file to disable the rules - its redundant.

Comment: Nowadays `TSLint` is deprecated and `eslint` should be used instead, but **`TSLint` did support overriding rules for sub-directory**, like: `{ "extends": "../tslint.json", ... }`, (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53715541/8740349)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2021;**

Nowadays `TSLint` is deprecated and `eslint` should be used instead, but **`TSLint` did support overriding rules for sub-directory**, like:

```json
{
    "extends": "../tslint.json",
    
    ...
}
```

> See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53715541/8740349

### Old answer

Seems like the only option so far is to disable them using the comment functionality.

Comment: BTW, there's an open [PR](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/3708) already to add this feature.

Comment: Which is declined though.